# UIWebView does not cover entire view in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, landscape

I am developing an iPad App that will load a webpage in a UIWebView modally when the user is authenticated through a login form. This works great, but when I rotate the device into landscape mode, the webview covers only 75% of the screen:

[image: screenshot showing the issue]

Here is the code from my login view controller:

```
    // Load storyboard for easy instatiation of the login view controller
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPad" bundle:nil];
    WebViewController *webController =
    (WebViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WebView"];

    // Present the embedded browser in fullscreen.
    [webController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];
    [self presentViewController:webController animated:YES completion: nil];
```

Comment: Note that if your app only does this (displaying an UIWebView after login), it will be rejected by Apple if you submit it to the App Store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using constraints or auto-resizing masks? If not, you might want to use them and make sure the web view covers the entire view's frame.

Comment: @Debopam - starting iOS 6 you can now use Auto-layout features that the SDK provides.

Answer (score 1):

All you gotta do is define the frame of `UIWebView` for landscape orientation in `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method of your `WebViewController`.

It goes something like this,

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {

 if(toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
 {
     webView.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0 768, 1024);
 }
 else 
 {
     webView.frame = CGRectMake (0, 0 1024, 768);
 }
 return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but surprisingly it did not have any effect. I thought that the resizing of the UIWebView would be automatic on rotation.

Comment: Ahh... I didn't see that you are building this app for iOS 6. Well  -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method is deprecated for iOS 6 that's why it didn't work and as @lostInTransit said Auto resizing will do it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use webView delegates
   2.Include this method

   - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
     [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
     }
     }
2. include this one also

   - (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
     {
     [self.webView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
     }